# while there is input from user

Tags: java, while-loop

I'm new to java. In my program, I have the user enter the integers that are being added to an array list. I need to set up a while loop that will be something like this:

```
arrayList = new ArrayList<int>; 
int i = scanner.nextInt();
while(there is input from user)
{
    arrayList.add(i);
}
```

I expect the user to enter 5 values. What do I put as the condition statement of the while loop. In other words, how do I say "while there is input?" Thanks

Comment: `new ArrayList<Integer>()`

Comment: `do{int i = scanner.nextInt();if(i==5)arrayList.add(i);}while(i!=5);`

Comment: How do you want your user to indicate that they are done entering values?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try something along the lines of

```
while(scanner.hasNextInt())
{
     arrayList.add(i);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
import java.util.Scanner;
import java.util.ArrayList;

public class A {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);
        ArrayList arrayList = new ArrayList<Integer>(); 
        int input;
        for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++)
        {
            input = scan.nextInt();
            arrayList.add(input);
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I tried below code and tested its working fine. let me know if u want another requirements.

```
import java.io.*;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class test {
    public static void main(String args[]){
   Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);
   ArrayList<Integer> arr = new ArrayList<Integer>();
   System.out.print("enter 5 numbers");
   int counter=1;
  while(scan.hasNextInt()){
      int i=scan.nextInt();
      arr.add(i);
     counter++;
     if(counter==5){
         scan.close();
         break;
     }
    }


    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

I believe, you're currently accepted answer has a very fatal (it never updates `i`). What you need is something more like this -

```
// arrayList = new ArrayList<int>; // And arrayList isn't a great name. But I have
                                   // no idea what they actually are. So  
                                   // just use a short name.  
List<Integer> al = new ArrayList<Inteeger>(); // <-- Use the interface type?
                                              // And, you have to use the wrapper type.
// int i = scanner.nextInt();
while (scanner.hasNextInt())
{
  al.add(scanner.nextInt()); // You don't need `i`.
}
```